# Why shows bad request instead working in postman

Tags: php, curl, header

I have faced a problem. In my postman application it works fine. It is a post method request. [This is my url link](https://technet.rapaport.com/HTTP/JSON/RetailFeed/GetSingleDiamond.aspx).

`Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

`Content-Type: text/plain`

`Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId= urr1e3hsehli50bqkw04ot3r`

```
{
    "request":{
        "header":{
            "username":"xxx", 
            "password":"xxx"
        },
        "body":{
            "diamond_id":"114752692",
            "shape":"Princess"
        }
    }
}
```

Generate this code in postman like below

```
curl --location --request POST 
'https://technet.rapaport.com/HTTP/JSON/RetailFeed/GetSingleDiamond.aspx' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--header 'Content-Type: text/plain' \
--header 'Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=urr1e3hsehli50bqkw04ot3r' \
--data-raw '{
    "request":{
        "header":{
            "username":"xxx", 
            "password":"xxx"
        },
        "body":{
            "diamond_id":"114752692",
            "shape":"Princess"
        }
    }
}'
```

But the problem in my php code. I convert this code in php and below like this.

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "https://technet.rapaport.com/HTTP/JSON/RetailFeed/GetSingleDiamond.aspx",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>"{\r\n\"request\": {\r\n\"header\":{\r\n\"username\":\"xxx\",\r\n \"password\": \"xxx\"\r\n},\r\n\"body\": {\r\n\"diamond_id\":\"114752692\", \r\n\"shape\":\"Princess\"\r\n}\r\n}\r\n}",
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "Content-Type: application/json",
        "Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=urr1e3hsehli50bqkw04ot3r"
    ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
```

In my localhost when I browse `http://localhost/price/index.php` it shows me the error.

**Bad Request - Invalid Header**

> HTTP Error 400. The request has an invalid header name. I don't know why it shows me the error.

Comment: Why are you setting **two** Content-Type headers?

Comment: Actually I don't know what should be. @Quentin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem just replace

```
"Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
"Content-Type: application/json",
"Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=urr1e3hsehli50bqkw04ot3r"
```

To

```
'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
'Content-Type' => 'text/plain',
'Cookie'       => 'ASP.NET_SessionId=wvxova2bwht020vw4begtpiw'
```

Now it works fine for me